# Issue retrieving token bearer in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios, bearer-token

being new to ReactJS I'm having some issues adding authentication using token bearer in my app. After a login the user should be redirected to the main page and the returned token is stored in order to add a authentication to perform request (POST)

However, it seems while the token is well stored (visible in the console) I'm still unable to perform request due to 401 status code

Here is my login.js which call /login POST request (worked with postman):

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './login.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function Login({ setIsLoggedIn }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [registrationMessage, setRegistrationMessage] = useState('');
  const [LoginMessage, setLoginMessage] = useState(''); 
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const apiBaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL;
  console.log("apiBaseUrl:", apiBaseUrl);

  const handleLogin = async () => {

     try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('username', username);
      formData.append('password', password);
      const response = await axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/login`, formData,{
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      if (response.status == 200) {

        const token = response.data.token;
        console.log('Token before storing:', token);

        localStorage.setItem('token', token.toString());
        console.log('Token after storing:', localStorage.getItem('token'));

        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        navigate('/');
      } else {
        setLoginMessage('Email ou mot de passe invalide');
      }
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during registration:',error);
        setLoginMessage('Email ou mot de passe invalide');
      }
     }
```

Here is my api.js that handle axios instance:

```
const apiBaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL;

const apiInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiBaseUrl, // FastAPI backend URL
});

// Include a function to set the authorization token for the API instance
apiInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    try {
      const token = await localStorage.getItem('token'); // Use await here
      console.log('Token:', token);
      if (token) {
        config.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting token from localStorage:', error);
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get('/votes'); // your API endpoint
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export default apiInstance;
```

And finally the POST request that needs authentication:

```
const response = await apiInstance.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/create_vote`, {
        first_name,
        last_name,
        gender,
        size: parseFloat(size),
        weight: parseFloat(weight), // Convert to float before sending
        birthday: dateTimeToSend,
      }, );
      console.log('Server response:', response);
  
      if (response.status === 201) {
        // If status code is 201 (Created), set a success message
        setResponseMessage('Merci votre vote a bien été pris en compte');
      } else {
        // For other status codes, you can set an error message or handle it as needed
        setResponseMessage('An error occurred. Please try again.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending data:', error);
      // Handle the error and set an appropriate error message
      setResponseMessage('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    }
  };
```

In advance, many thanks !